# How to find symbol for MethodGroup in Roslyn 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, microsoft.codeanalysis

I am trying to use Roslyn to identify the symbol behind a method group reference. This worked fine using `SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo` in earlier versions of Roslyn, but in the latest version no symbol is found. What is the right way to perform this mapping?

```
var ws = new AdhocWorkspace();
var proj = ws.AddProject("test", "C#")
    .AddMetadataReference(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location));
proj = proj.WithParseOptions(proj.ParseOptions.WithFeatures(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "IOperation", "true" }}));
var doc = proj.AddDocument("test.cs", SourceText.From(@"namespace Test {
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Func<int> x = Foo; // want to map Foo to one of the methods below!
        }

        private static int Foo() => 7;

        private static int Foo(int x) => 8
    }
}"));
proj = doc.Project;

var compilation = proj.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
var tree = doc.GetSyntaxTreeAsync().Result;
var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
var fooToken = tree.GetRoot().DescendantTokens()
    .First(t => t.Text.ToString() == "Foo");

Console.WriteLine(model.GetSymbolInfo(fooToken.Parent).Symbol); // null
Console.WriteLine(model.GetMemberGroup(fooToken.Parent).Length); // 2
```

As the example, shows GetMemberGroup does return results, but it returns results for both Foo() methods rather than the specific one I'm referencing.

How can I extract the exact referenced symbol?

Answer (score 2):

There are several syntax errors in the code below.

```
namespace Test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Func<int> x = Foo; // want to map Foo to one of the methods below!
        }

        private static int Foo() => 7;

        private static int Foo(int x) => 8
    }
}
```

You need to add a using for `System` or fully qualify `Func<int>` as `System.Func<int>`.  `int Foo(int x) => 8` is also missing a semicolon at the end.  Due to these errors, overload resolution fails.  The easiest way to check why a symbol is not selected is to look at the candidate reason like so: `model.GetSymbolInfo(fooToken.Parent).CandidateReason`, which will tell you that there was an overload resolution failure. You can also call `compilation.GetDiagnostics()` to see what errors exist in the code.

[image: watch window with errors]

If we correct these errors overload resolution will succeed

```
var ws = new AdhocWorkspace();
var proj = ws.AddProject("test", "C#")
                .AddMetadataReference(
                    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location));
proj = proj.WithParseOptions(proj.ParseOptions
    .WithFeatures(new Dictionary<string, string> { ["IOperation"] = "true" }));
var doc = proj.AddDocument("test.cs", SourceText.From(@"using System;
namespace Test {
    public class Program{
        public static void Main(){
            Func<int> x = Foo;
        }
        private static int Foo() => 7;
        private static int Foo(int x) => 8;
    }
}"));
proj = doc.Project;

var compilation = proj.GetCompilationAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var tree = doc.GetSyntaxTreeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
var fooToken = tree.GetRoot().DescendantTokens().First(t => t.Text == "Foo");
Console.WriteLine(model.GetSymbolInfo(fooToken.Parent).Symbol);
Console.WriteLine(model.GetMemberGroup(fooToken.Parent).Length);
```

[image: porgram output]
[image: watch window without errors]